# Sharepoint - Accessing PDF links via Chrome

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, cross-browser

Firstly let me state that I have zero experience with Sharepoint so this may be a pretty stupid question.

I started a new job yesterday and part of the induction is viewing the company literature via their Sharepoint portal.  I've noticed that whenever I try to access an embedded PDF link via Chrome it seems like it's a broken link and appears to do a Google search instead.  Yet when I try the exact same steps using IE all works as expected.

I don't want to raise this with my boss if it's going to make me look a little stupid!  Is there some cross browser issue with PDF links?

Thanks.

Comment: well.. first obvious question is, did your company allow you to install Chrome? Typically de-facto standard is IE, and most companies authenticate you for servers, something Chrome might not do in the same way as a corporate configured IE setup.  I would suggest asking your boss what software is allowed first.

Comment: Yes, Chrome is installed on the machines already.

Answer (score 1):

Darren, try flushing the cache in Chrome, and if necessary, log off and log back into your computer. We've had the same problem with Chrome and Google doesn't seem to be fixing the problem (although they might point the finger back at Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have the same issue with Chrome and Firefox
Sharepoint is optimized for IE and vice versa

You also can't open Files with the "Check in and Check out" functionality because only IE is able to do that from Sharepoint (Other Browsers will just Download the File)

You can try using AddOns like IE-Tab
(simply uses the IE algorithms within FF and Chrome for specific Sites)
But its better to use Sharepoint with IE